# Php: How can I check if a checkbox is checked without submitting the form?

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

How can I check if a checkbox is checked without submitting the form first? 
I want to make a check out page and there is a billing adress form and a shipping adress form. I want the shipping adress form to disappear when I check a box that says "Shipping address is the same as my billing address". I want to do this without reloading the page. Is this possible? If yes, how? And if no, is there a different way i can get the same result using php?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: well, you can forget PHP for this - you need to use Javascript. Assign an event listener to the checkbox that monitors it's checked status - use the event handler function to hide/show the form depending upon the checkbox status

Comment: PHP is run on the server, Javascript will need to be run client side for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with jquery base on your question, but it not actually php you really need but jquery.

**Jquery prop**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $("#result").html("Checkbox is checked.");
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $("#result").html("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    });
});
```

You also you **jquery selector**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#result").html("Checkbox is checked.");
        }
        else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
            $("#result").html("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without submitting the form means a front-end validation.

On your trigger, try to use this:

```
document.getElementById("your-id").checked
```

Example:

```
function formTrigger()
{
   let checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
   if (checkBox.checked == true){
     console.log("it's checked.");
   }
}
```